# integration involving differentiation by chain rule

Tags: calculus

How can I show this $2x$ appearing in the answer to

Use chain rule to find derivative w.r.t $x$ of $\int_x^{x^2}\sin t^2 dt$ as

$2x\sin x^4 - \sin x .$

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental theorem of calculus stays that, if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b],$ then $$F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$$ is differentiable and $F'(x)=f(x).$ Now, note that, if $a$ is any fixed number between $x$ and $x^2,$ then $$\int_x^{x^2}f(t)dt=\int_x^{a}f(t)dt+\int_a^{x^2}f(t)dt=F(x^2)-F(x).$$  Thus, applying the chain rule, you get that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^{x^2}f(t)dt=F'(x^2)\cdot 2x-F'(x)=2xf(x^2)-f(x).$$